# Norm of operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H := \ell^2(\mathbb N)$ and for $f \in \ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ definie $T_f:H \to H : g \mapsto f\cdot g$. This is well definied. I want to show that $\| T_f \| = \| f \|_\infty$. It is easy to show that $\|T_f\| \leq \|f\|_\infty$. To show equality I must find a function $g:\mathbb N \to \mathbb C$ s.t. $\|g\|_2 \leq 1$ and $\|f\cdot g\|_2 = \|f\|_\infty$. That is
$$
 \sup_N \sum_{n=1}^N |f(n)g(n)|^2 = \left( \sup_n |f(n)| \right)^2
$$ and 
$$
 \sup_N  \sum_{n=1}^N |g(n)|^2 \leq 1
$$ Since this the sums are all over positive elements we could replace the $\sup$ by $\lim$. 
Am I proceeding right ?

Comment: The sup need not be attained in general for an operator norm (the unit ball is not compact here). Usually, one tries to find a sequence $\|g_k\|_2=1$ such that $\|T_f(g_k)\|_2$ tends to the upper bound we found in the first place (or we do that with $\epsilon$'s). Here it all depends whether $\|f\|_\infty$ is attained, but both cases can be handled simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can not find $g$ for which the norm of operator is attained. To prove the desidred result it is enough for each $\varepsilon>0$ to find $g\in \ell_2(\mathbb{N})$ such that $\Vert f\cdot g\Vert_2\geq \Vert f\Vert_\infty-\varepsilon$. Now I suggest to consider
$g=\Vert\chi_{\{k\}}\Vert_2^{-1}\chi_{\{k\}}$ for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(k)|\geq\Vert f\Vert_\infty-\varepsilon$.

Comment: It is easier to just pick one $k$ in $A$ and set $g=\chi_{\{k\}}$.

Comment: ok${}{}{}{}{}{}$